# Подключение внешней обработка Альфа-Авто 5

Tags: 1с

Добрый вечер, господа! Есть внешняя обработка, хочу загрузить ее в Альфа-Авто 5, с которой доселе не работал особо. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону курить? Справочника "Внешние печатные формы и обработки", как в человеческих типовых конфигурациях, нет.

Comment: Ну во первых) какая база? Скуль/файловая? Через конфигуратор добавляем на сервере или через морду?

Comment: Альфа-Авто 5 от рарус. Через морду. Файловая.

Comment: Если через морду, то проверить есть ли возможность их вообще подключать в настройках.

Comment: И чисто риторический вопрос- а чего не положить ее через конфигуратор?

Comment: Нужно именно в базу - нужно проверить поведение своей обработки во встроенном варианте.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, в общем. Если кому надо будет:

Справочники -> Структура компании -> Внешние печатные формы

Раскрываем дерево "Внешние обработки"

ПКМ на правой панели -> "Добавить", заполняем наименование, льем файл и записываем элемент

Теперь можем открывать ее через "Обработки" -> "Внешние обработки и отчеты"

P.S. Добавить обработку через "Внешние обработки и отчеты" нельзя.